# AntDesign forms or React Hook Form

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hook-form

i was searching which are the differences and the advantages/disadvantages of using one or another but i couldn't find anything. Is it justified to add another library or simply use the AntDesign form validation? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AntDesign is an ui-library.

My favorite set is `react-hook-form`(manager) + `yup`(validation tool).

You can check performance benchmark [react-hook-form](https://react-hook-form.com/advanced-usage/). It is one of the best tool in community.